# Did I do anything wrong when config Server.xml to point another domain into a folder that is not a ROOT folder in webapps folder?

Tags: apache, tomcat, webserver

Ok, I have a main domain: `mainDM.com` (which is the domain of the app named `mainDM`) bought from Godaddy. I also bought a Godaddy Win2000 VPS with IP adress `xxx.xx.xx.xx`.

In Godaddy I pointed that domain into `xxx.xx.xx.xx`.

In Tomcat server, in `webapps` folder, there is a `ROOT` folder & I put all html files of mainDM application into the `ROOT` folder. Everything work fines. That is when I opened `mainDM.com` I can see my app running OK.

Now, I developed another app called `otherDM` & I also bought a domain `otherDM.com` in Godaddy & I also pointed it into `xxx.xx.xx.xx`. Now when opening `otherDM.com`, I do not see the `otherDM` app but `mainDM` app. So I want to config `server.xml` so that when I open `otherDM.com`, it will show `otherDM` web app. **Note:** There is an `otherDM` folder that containing all html files of `otherDM` app in `webapps` folder.

Here is what I did at `server.xml`, but nothing happened.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
      <Host name="otherDM.com" appbase="otherDM" autoDeploy="true" unpackWARs="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="otherDM_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

I did restart my Tomcat server but nothing happened, each time I open the otherDM.com then it shows the mainDM app. However, if I open `otherDM.com/otherDM` or open `mainDM.com/otherDM` then I can see `otherDM` app.

**Did I do anything wrong? How to fix?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed,

First, I do what Stefan said, created

```
[CATALINA_HOME]/otherDM
```

And put all html files into the ROOT of `mainDM` and `otherDM` accordingly.

Then, add a `Host` into `server.xml`

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="mainDM" ...
 <Host name="otherDM.com"  appBase="otherDM" ...
```

Finally I need to add ROOT.xml into `C:\tomcat7\conf\Catalina\otherDM.com\ROOT.xml`

```
<Context 
  docBase="C:/tomcat7/otherDM/ROOT" 
  path="" 
  reloadable="true" 
/>
```

AN now it work perfectly and I can add many domains as i can

Answer (score 0):

The "appbase" attribute of a "host" tag points, if relative, as in your case, to a directory below CATALINA_HOME. So just create two folders like this:

```
[CATALINA_HOME]/mainDomain
[CATALINA_HOME]/otherDomain
```

and create two ROOT folder in them. Copy you apps into the ROOT directories.

Then set the appbase to:

```
 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="mainDomain" ...
 <Host name="mainDomain.com"  appBase="mainDomain" ...
 <Host name="otherDomain.com"  appBase="otherDomain" ...
```

Comment: ok, I put a ROOT.xml file (empty file) into conf/Catalina/otherDM.com and then now it shows blank page